# Security - Should a pdf directory be located outside the root directory on a website

Tags: security, web, webserver

I'm going to store pdf's on my website so they are available online. Should the directory be outside the root director or is it safe enough to keep it inside the root directory? What is standard practice for storing this type of file. There will not be any sensitive date on the files. I'm worried about the potential of the files being hacked or modified.

Answer (score 2):

If the PDFs are available for general download and you simply link to them, there should be no problem putting them directly into your webroot.

You say you are worried about files being hacked or modified on the server. Bear in mind that if an intruder gains access to your webroot, all bets are off.  It doesn't matter at that point if you have PDFs or not in the webroot - because the attacker can just edit your php or asp pages and cause havoc.  This would be easier than editing your PDFs and trying to "execute" them.

There are lots of techniques for securing your webroot.  Unless you know what you are doing, do not allow file uploads. Disable this at all costs. Next, use the correct permissions on folders. I'm afraid apache/linux is much better for this than windoze.  But for instance set permissions so files in the webroot can be read and executed but not written.  There are more things you can do, like Apache chroot, but this gets complicated.

Last, bear in mind that by far the most common vulnerability in web applications is SQL injection, so if you are using dynamic pages make sure your are protected against this.  Actually gaining access to webroot files tends to be a consequence of a hack rather than the initial hack, unless of course you have set it up all wrong!